# Text field in Illustrator looks slightly rotated while rotation is on 0°

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm experiencing a strange problem in Illustrator. Some text is 'sagging' for no reason in a text field. I had this happen before and in old cases it turned out I accidentally slightly rotated a text field. But now the rotation is on 0, and the text is still somehow sagging.

You can see it on the words at the right side of the text fields:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Typically a display issue.. is it present at all zoom levels? It may be that the pixel density of your monitor can't reflect the true position.

Comment: Just because the rotation field says "0" it doesn't mean that the text field can't be rotated (or distorted in some other way). Try to compare the Y-values of the points of the upper left and upper right corner using Direct Selection Tool.

Comment: Because the anomaly only appears on the top 3 lines of a single piece of area text - and SKIPS the line in the middle, I really think it's a display/preview error. Illustrator is very , very prone to such things. Switching to outline mode to check may show everything perfectly straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it's a massive anticlimax, but rebooting my PC solved the issue. The text looks correct now.

Comment: perhaps you should consider deleting the question then, GD.SE is not a bug-solving website

Comment: Well, I didn't know it was a bug when I asked this question. Also it might be interesting for others struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Double check a few settings in Illustrator:

**Character Palette:**

1.) Check that you did not accidentally apply a negative baseline shift to portions of the text.

[image: Baseline Shift]

2.) Check the settings for the method in which Illustrator is anti-aliasing the font, you may have better results with one of the other options than your current setting.

[image: Anti-Aliasing]

**Illustrator Preferences**

3.) Preferences > General: Check that Anti-aliased Artwork is checked.

[image: Anti-aliased Artwork]